# Faster alternatives to numpy.argmax/argmin which is slow

Tags: python, numpy

I am using a lot of `argmin` and `argmax` in Python.

Unfortunately, the function is very slow.

I have done some searching around, and the best I can find is here:

http://lemire.me/blog/archives/2008/12/17/fast-argmax-in-python/

```
def fastest_argmax(array):
    array = list( array )
    return array.index(max(array))
```

Unfortunately, this solution is still only half as fast as `np.max`, and I think I should be able to find something as fast as `np.max`.

```
x = np.random.randn(10)
%timeit np.argmax( x )
10000 loops, best of 3: 21.8 us per loop

%timeit fastest_argmax( x )    
10000 loops, best of 3: 20.8 us per loop
```

As a note, I am applying this to a Pandas DataFrame Groupby

E.G.

```
%timeit grp2[ 'ODDS' ].agg( [ fastest_argmax ] )
100 loops, best of 3: 8.8 ms per loop

%timeit grp2[ 'ODDS' ].agg( [ np.argmax ] )
100 loops, best of 3: 11.6 ms per loop
```

Where `grp2[ 'ODDS' ].head()` looks like this:

```
EVENT_ID   SELECTION_ID        
104601100  4367029       682508    3.05
                         682509    3.15
                         682510    3.25
                         682511    3.35
           5319660       682512    2.04
                         682513    2.08
                         682514    2.10
                         682515    2.12
                         682516    2.14
           5510310       682520    4.10
                         682521    4.40
                         682522    4.50
                         682523    4.80
                         682524    5.30
           5559264       682526    5.00
                         682527    5.30
                         682528    5.40
                         682529    5.50
                         682530    5.60
           5585869       682533    1.96
                         682534    1.97
                         682535    1.98
                         682536    2.02
                         682537    2.04
           6064546       682540    3.00
                         682541    2.74
                         682542    2.76
                         682543    2.96
                         682544    3.05
104601200  4916112       682548    2.64
                         682549    2.68
                         682550    2.70
                         682551    2.72
                         682552    2.74
           5315859       682557    2.90
                         682558    2.92
                         682559    3.05
                         682560    3.10
                         682561    3.15
           5356995       682564    2.42
                         682565    2.44
                         682566    2.48
                         682567    2.50
                         682568    2.52
           5465225       682573    1.85
                         682574    1.89
                         682575    1.91
                         682576    1.93
                         682577    1.94
           5773661       682588    5.00
                         682589    4.40
                         682590    4.90
                         682591    5.10
           6013187       682592    5.00
                         682593    4.20
                         682594    4.30
                         682595    4.40
                         682596    4.60
104606300  2489827       683438    4.00
                         683439    3.90
                         683440    3.95
                         683441    4.30
                         683442    4.40
           3602724       683446    2.16
                         683447    2.32
Name: ODDS, Length: 65, dtype: float64
```

Comment: I'd recommend viewing the numpy source code for how they did it. Here's a link: https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/1e22553c37e9112bf2426c1b060275419f906d8d/numpy/core/src/multiarray/calculation.c Try to mimic their approach.

Comment: "Inefficient" doesn't even begin to describe your so-called "fastest_argmax".

Comment: On my notebook pc `%timeit np.argmax( x )` with `x.shape == 10` took only 1 us, what's your numpy version.?

Comment: The code you link is mostly about handling the `axis` parameter properly. The actual `argmin/max` is performed by the functions defined [here](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/master/numpy/core/src/multiarray/arraytypes.c.src#L2768). Note that it is templated code, see [here](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/distutils.html#conversion-of-src-files) for a description of the syntax.

Comment: ivan - do you have any suggestions on more efficient versions?

Comment: My numpy version is 1.8.1

Comment: I can check the format of the `Pandas`'s data if you give me a hint how to construct the object you're working with (I've no experience with `Pandas`).

Answer (score 19):

It turns out that `np.argmax` *is* blazingly fast, but *only* with the native numpy arrays. With foreign data, almost all the time is spent on conversion:

```
In [194]: print platform.architecture()
('64bit', 'WindowsPE')

In [5]: x = np.random.rand(10000)
In [57]: l=list(x)
In [123]: timeit numpy.argmax(x)
100000 loops, best of 3: 6.55 us per loop
In [122]: timeit numpy.argmax(l)
1000 loops, best of 3: 729 us per loop
In [134]: timeit numpy.array(l)
1000 loops, best of 3: 716 us per loop
```

I called your function "inefficient" because it first converts everything to list, then iterates through it 2 times (effectively, 3 iterations + list construction).

I was going to suggest something like this that only iterates once:

```
def imax(seq):
    it=iter(seq)
    im=0
    try: m=it.next()
    except StopIteration: raise ValueError("the sequence is empty")
    for i,e in enumerate(it,start=1):
        if e>m:
            m=e
            im=i
    return im
```

But, your version turns out to be faster because it iterates many times but does it in C, rather that Python, code. C is just that much faster - even considering the fact a great deal of time is spent on conversion, too:

```
In [158]: timeit imax(x)
1000 loops, best of 3: 883 us per loop
In [159]: timeit fastest_argmax(x)
1000 loops, best of 3: 575 us per loop

In [174]: timeit list(x)
1000 loops, best of 3: 316 us per loop
In [175]: timeit max(l)
1000 loops, best of 3: 256 us per loop
In [181]: timeit l.index(0.99991619010758348)  #the greatest number in my case, at index 92
100000 loops, best of 3: 2.69 us per loop
```

So, the key knowledge to speeding this up further is to know which format the data in your sequence natively is (e.g. whether you can omit the conversion step or use/write another functionality native to that format).

Btw, you're likely to get some speedup by using `aggregate(max_fn)` instead of `agg([max_fn])`.

Answer (score 15):

For those that came for a short numpy-free snippet that returns the index of the first minimum value:

```
def argmin(a):
    return min(range(len(a)), key=lambda x: a[x])
a = [6, 5, 4, 1, 1, 3, 2]
argmin(a)  # returns 3
```

Comment: mhm, can be converted to `argmax` just by changing `min` to `max`?

Comment: mhm, yes it can

Comment: very elegant solution. Thank you sir.

Answer (score 2):

Can you post some code? Here is the result on my pc:

```
x = np.random.rand(10000)
%timeit np.max(x)
%timeit np.argmax(x)
```

output:

```
100000 loops, best of 3: 7.43 µs per loop
100000 loops, best of 3: 11.5 µs per loop
```

Comment: What's your terminal? A stock console font can't print the mu letter AFAIK.

Comment: @ivan_pozdeev - Most modern console emulators have at least some (usually full) unicode support (even xterm).