# Python merge lists in place to maintain external references

Tags: python, dictionary

I am not sure if this is possible in Python, but performance to my application is critical and I have the following scenario.

I am attempting merge two disjoint sets with the following implementation. I have a dictionary of sorted lists, where the keys in the dictionary point to the sorted list which holds the value (by reference). Like this

```
l1 = [1, 2, 3]
l2 = [4, 5, 6]

d = {1: l1, 2: l1, 3: l1, 4: l2, 5: l2, 6: l2}
```

Now I want to merge the two lists in place such that each key in the dictionary refers to the same underlying list like

```
l1 = l2 = l1 + l2
```

But this won't affect the references held within the dictionary, since a new list is created.

Speed is critical here, so I don't want to create new lists and reassign references to each key in the dictionary.

EDIT

I would expect the following code to run without an assertion error after this operation

```
for v in d:
    assert d[v] is l1
```

Comment: and how should look the final result?

Comment: I second what @RomanPerekhrest has asked. What exactly should you output be? Could you give an example?

Comment: try `l1[:] = l2[:] = l1 + l2`

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest The final result should be `for v in d: d[v] == l1`

Comment: @shane But you said each key would equal `l1 + l2`. No?

Comment: @leaf Right, I mean each key will reference the same list, which should be the combined result of `l1` and `l2`

Comment: Instead of holding list references in your dict, hold indexes. That way you can replace the list and it won't matter. Holding references seems pretty fragile to me.

Comment: @shane So would something like this work `nd = {key: l1 + l2 for key in d.keys()}`?

Comment: @leaf I think that's the *opposite* of what shane wants. The closest would be Patrick Haugh's answer. Also, no need for `d.keys` to iterate of dictionary keys. Just `d` will suffice.

Comment: @leaf I am looking to avoid re-iterating over `d` if possible

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga I know `d` would suffice. I was being explicit for the for the OP's sake.

Comment: With `@Patrick Haugh's` suggestion, `d[4] is l1` is `False`, but `d[4]==l1` is `True`.  That is `l1==l2` but their `ids` are not the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

References work similar to pointers: each one uniquely identifies an object, and only it. So, `l1` and `l2` that your dictionary elements hold are *different* references.

Thus, you can't magically make them the same without actually editing the dictionary.

All you can do is make `l1` and `l2` hold identical values.

Comment: Fair, I suppose I am looking for a sort of double pointer as I would have in C++, which is not available in Python. Thanks for making this explicit.

Comment: if I have 1000 elements keying to `px = &p1` and 1000 elements keying to `py = &p2`, and `p1` and `p2` are type `List *`, then I can combine the lists and set `p1` and `p2` to point to the new list without modifying the value of 2000 elements. I did say I did not want to create a new list, but that was slightly misleading since it would be impossible to combine the lists otherwise

Comment: See - your dictionary items are not `List *` but `List **` here. And to check if they are the same, you don't compare their values but dereference them once and then compare. Likewise, to do that in Python, what your `dict` entries hold, `l1` and `l2`, should not be lists proper but "proxies", e.g. [like this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1145722/simulating-pointers-in-python), and you should not compare _them_ with `is` but the references they hold.

Comment: This, however, may be not pythonic unless you have other reasons to use "indirect references" besides performance gain ([which may even be nonexistent](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26820109/648265)): having two sets of values in a `dict` which are really the same kinda defeats the purpose of two sets of values (and of a `dict` in the first place). Python is consciously designed for programmer's performance at the cost of code performance - you first write clean and correct code and only then check if you need optimization.