# Time complexity / algorithm used for pandas `idxmax` method

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, argmax

Hi I am trying to understand how efficient `pd.DataFrame.idxmax` to see if it is worth replacing with a custom algorithm which might be more efficient (ie using binary search for example).

I would like to understand the algorithm behind this method or at least its complexity however I have had no luck so far. Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [source](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/v1.1.3/pandas/core/frame.py#L8806-L8877), the authors state `This method is the DataFrame version of ndarray.argmax`. This method `argmax` have a time complexity of `O(N)` as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63734910/theoretical-average-case-runtime-complexity-of-numpy-argmax). It is then reasonable to assume that `pd.DataFrame.idxmax` would have the same time complexity.

If you would like to implement your own search algorithm, keep in mind that binary search as you proposed requires a sorted array of items, that might not be the case for a `DataFrame` column.