# Fastest way to repeatedly find indices of K largest values in an iteratively partially updated array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, performance, max

In a complex-valued array `a` with `nsel = ~750000` elements, I repeatedly (`>~10^6` iterations) update `nchange < ~1000` elements. After each iteration, in the absolute-squared, real-valued array `b`, I need to find the indices of the `K` largest values (`K` can be assumed to be small, for sure `K <= ~50`, in practice likely `K <= ~10`). The `K` indices do not need to be sorted.

The updated values and their indices change in each iteration and they depend on the (a priori) unknown elements of `a` corresponding to the largest values of `b` and their indices. Nonetheless, let us assume they are essentially random, with exception that one specific element (typically (one of) the largest value(s)) is always included among the updated values. Important: After an update, the new largest value(s) might be among the non-updated elements.

Below is a minimal example. For simplicity, it demonstrates only one of the 10^6 (looped) iterations. We can find the indices of the `K` largest values using `b.argmax()` (for `K = 1`) or `b.argpartition()` (arbitrary `K`, general case, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/23734295/5269892). However, due to the large size of `b` (`nsel`), going over the full arrays to find the indices of the largest values is very slow. Combined with the large number of iterations, this forms the bottleneck of a larger code (the nonlinear deconvolution algorithm CLEAN) I am using into which this step is embedded.

I have already asked the question how to find the largest value (the case `K = 1`) most efficiently, see [Python most efficient way to find index of maximum in partially changed array](https://stackoverflow.com/q/73039544/5269892). The [accepted solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73043775/5269892) relies on accessing `b` only partially by splitting the data into chunks and (re-)computing the maxima of only the chunks for which some elements were updated. A speed-up of `> 7x` is thus achieved.

According to the author [@Jérôme Richard](https://stackoverflow.com/users/12939557/j%C3%A9r%C3%B4me-richard) (thanks for your help!), this solution can unfortunately not be easily generalized to `K > 1`. As suggested by him, a possible alternative may be a binary search tree. Now my

**Questions: How is such a binary tree implemented in practice and how do we then find the indices of the largest values most efficiently (and if possible, easily)? Do you have other solutions for the fastest way to repeatedly find the indices of the `K` largest values in the partially updated array?**

Note: In each iteration I will need `b` (or a copy of it) later again as a numpy array. If possible, the solution should be mostly python-based, calling C from python or using Cython or `numba` is ok. I currently use `python 3.7.6, numpy 1.21.2`.

```
import numpy as np

# some array shapes ('nnu_use' and 'nm'), number of total values ('nvals'), number of selected values ('nsel';
# here 'nsel' == 'nvals'; in general 'nsel' <= 'nvals') and number of values to be changed ('nchange' << 'nsel')
nnu_use, nm = 10418//2 + 1, 144
nvals = nnu_use * nm
nsel = nvals
nchange = 1000

# number of largest peaks to be found
K = 10

# fix random seed, generate random 2D 'Fourier transform' ('a', complex-valued), compute power ('b', real-valued),
# and two 2D arrays for indices of axes 0 and 1
np.random.seed(100)
a = np.random.rand(nsel) + 1j * np.random.rand(nsel)
b = a.real ** 2 + a.imag ** 2
inu_2d = np.tile(np.arange(nnu_use)[:,None], (1,nm))
im_2d = np.tile(np.arange(nm)[None,:], (nnu_use,1))

# select 'nsel' random indices and get 1D arrays of the selected 2D indices
isel = np.random.choice(nvals, nsel, replace=False)
inu_sel, im_sel = inu_2d.flatten()[isel], im_2d.flatten()[isel]

def do_update_iter(a, b):
    # find index of maximum, choose 'nchange' indices of which 'nchange - 1' are random and the remaining one is the
    # index of the maximum, generate random complex numbers, update 'a' and compute updated 'b'
    imax = b.argmax()
    ichange = np.concatenate(([imax],np.random.choice(nsel, nchange-1, replace=False)))
    a_change = np.random.rand(nchange) + 1j*np.random.rand(nchange)
    a[ichange] = a_change
    b[ichange] = a_change.real ** 2 + a_change.imag ** 2
    return a, b, ichange

# do an update iteration on 'a' and 'b'
a, b, ichange = do_update_iter(a, b)

# find indices of largest K values
ilarge = b.argpartition(-K)[-K:]
```

Comment: So you have to execute this code multiple times? Or just once? Is that I just don't see `>~10^6` iterations

Comment: I need to execute this code, i.e. the update and finding the indices of the maximum values, a lot of times, say 10^6 (order of magnitude). The code example only shows one iteration, so to say. I'll clarify my post. But the code snippet is part of a larger algorithm I am using (the deconvolution method CLEAN), which runs about 10^6 iterations in a loop.

Comment: Honestly, the existing Python tree implementations are very disappointing. They are very slow. Even implementations like `SortedDict` of `sortedcontainers` claiming being fast with shiny benchmarks (suspiciously) showing faster performance than C++ turn out to be very slow (far more than C++ actually). Calling pure Python code does not help though it does not seems to be the bottleneck. Writing an optimized binary tree in Numba is a pretty huge work (hundreds of lines of code if not thousands). Cython may be the best option so to be able to use C++ containers and benefit from native execution.

Comment: Not to mention the binary tree approach is not as simple as expected: `b` must contain unique values if a basic tree is used. Otherwise a special implementation needs to be used so to keep duplicates adding more complications on top of the balancing algorithm. In addition, if the order of `b` matter (which is apparently the case), the tree must map the values correctly. C++ has the container `std::multimap` specifically for that. It also has iterators to keep track of nodes during updates. IDK any other native language providing such useful features by default (while being fast).

Comment: Indeed, python is very slow. In my original post I wanted to avoid C (if possible) simply because I don't know C much (my mistake) and thus I might run into problems modifying or maintaining the code. However, a faster, reasonably-sized Cython snippet or call to C from python solely for finding the indices of the largest values would nonetheless be perfectly fine.

Comment: @Jérôme Richard: If I may ask, how would an efficient implementation using Cython/C++ with the `std::multimap` container you mentioned look like (including the conversion from and back to numpy arrays)? Thanks a lot!

Comment: @bproxauf [This](https://cython.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/userguide/wrapping_CPlusPlus.html) page in interesting to know how to use C++ objects in Cython. Unfortunately, it also show that not all the STL is supported yet. More especially, `std::multimap` is not supported. This means an additional level of indirection is required or that one need to use `std::map<Key, std::vector<Value>>` with more complex accesses/updates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried to implement a **Cython solution based on C++ containers** (for 64-bit float values). The good news is that it is faster than a naive `np.argpartition`. The bad news is that it is quite complex and not much faster: **3~4 times faster**.

One main issue is that Cython do not implement the `std::multimap` container which is the most useful one. It is possible to implement this container using a `std::map<Key, std::vector<Value>>` type but it makes the code significantly more complex and also less efficient (due to the additional cache-unfriendly indirection in memory). If one can guarantee that there is no duplicates in `b`, then performance can be significantly better (up to x2) since `std::map` can be used instead. Furthermore, Cython do not seems to accept recent C++11/C++17/C++20 features making the code more cumbersome to read/write. This is sad since [some feature like `extract` and rvalues-references] can make the code faster.

Another main issue is that the execution time is bounded by **cache-misses** (>75% on my machine) because the binary RB-trees are **not cache friendly**.   The thing is the overall data structure is very likely bigger than the CPU caches. Indeed, `750_000*(8*2+4) = 15_000_000 bytes` are at least required to store the key-values, not to mention a similar amount of memory is needed to store node pointers of the tree data structure and most processor caches are smaller than 30 MB. This is mainly a problem during the update because of **random accesses**: each lookup/insert require `log2(nsel)` fetches in RAM and the latency of the RAM is typically of several dozens of nanoseconds. Additionally, (C++) RB-trees do not support key updates so a remove+insert is required. I tried to mitigate this problem using a parallel prefetching approach. Unfortunately, it was generally slower in practice...

In practice, the extraction of the K-largest items is very fast (about few microseconds for 1000 items and 750_000 values in the tree) while the update takes about 1.0-1.5 millisecond. Meanwhile, `np.argpartition` takes ~4.5 milliseconds.

Some people reported (eg. [here](https://github.com/Rufflewind/bench-maps)) that `std::map` is actually quite slow when the number of item is quite big. Thus, it may be a good idea to use another non-standard C++ implementation. I expect B-trees to be faster in this case. The [Google Abseil](https://abseil.io/docs/cpp/guides/container) library contains such containers and they are certainly significantly faster. That being said, it certainly require a wrapping some code which can be tedious. Alternatively, one can write a full C++ class and call it from Cython.

---

### Implementation

Here is the implementation (and an example of usage at the end):

- maxtree.pyx:

```py
# distutils: language = c++

import numpy as np
cimport numpy as np
cimport cython

# See: https://cython.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/userguide/wrapping_CPlusPlus.html
from libcpp.vector cimport vector
from libcpp.map cimport map
from libcpp.pair cimport pair
from cython.operator cimport dereference as deref, preincrement as inc


@cython.boundscheck(False)  # Deactivate bounds checking
@cython.wraparound(False)   # Deactivate negative indexing
cdef class MaxTree:
    cdef map[double, vector[int]] data
    cdef int itemCount

    # Build a tree from `b`
    def __init__(self, double[::1] b):
        cdef map[double, vector[int]].iterator it
        cdef pair[double, vector[int]] node
        cdef double val
        cdef int i

        # Temporary node used to ease insertion
        node.second.resize(1)

        # Iterate over `b` items so to add them in the tree
        for i in range(b.size):
            val = b[i]
            it = self.data.find(val)

            if it == self.data.end():
                # Value not found: add a new node
                node.first = val
                node.second[0] = i
                self.data.insert(node)
            else:
                # Value found: adds a new duplicate in an existing node
                deref(it).second.push_back(i)

        self.itemCount = b.size

    def size(self):
        return self.itemCount

    # Get the index (in the original `b` array) of the K-largest values
    def getKlargest(self, int count):
        cdef map[double, vector[int]].reverse_iterator rit
        cdef int vecSize
        cdef int* vecData
        cdef int i, j
        cdef int[::1] resultView

        if count > self.itemCount:
            count = self.itemCount

        result = np.empty(count, dtype=np.int32)
        resultView = result
        i = 0

        rit = self.data.rbegin()
        while rit != self.data.rend():
            vecSize = deref(rit).second.size()
            vecData = deref(rit).second.data()
            # Note: indices are not always sorted here due to the update
            for j in range(vecSize-1, -1, -1):
                resultView[i] = vecData[j]
                i += 1
                count -= 1
                if count <= 0:
                    return resultView
            inc(rit)

        return result

    # Set the values of `b` at the index `index` to `values` and update the tree accordingly
    def update(self, double[::1] b, int[::1] index, double[::1] values):
        cdef map[double, vector[int]].iterator it
        cdef pair[double, vector[int]] node
        #cdef pair[map[double, vector[int]].iterator, bool] infos
        cdef int idx, i, j, vecSize, indexSize
        cdef double oldValue, newValue
        cdef int* vecData

        assert b.size == self.itemCount
        assert index.size == values.size
        assert np.min(index) >= 0 and np.max(index) < b.size

        # Temporary node used to ease insertion
        node.second.resize(1)

        for i in range(index.size):
            idx = index[i]
            oldValue = b[idx]
            newValue = values[i]

            it = self.data.find(oldValue)
            assert it != self.data.end()

            # Update the tree
            if deref(it).second.size() == 1:
                # Remove the node from the tree and add a new one because keys are immutable
                # Assume `index` is correct/coherent and the tree is correctly updated for sake of performance
                #assert deref(it).second[0] == idx
                self.data.erase(it)
                node.first = newValue
                node.second[0] = idx
                infos = self.data.insert(node)
                inserted = infos.second
                if not inserted:
                    # Duplicate
                    it = infos.first
                    deref(it).second.push_back(idx)
            else:
                # Tricky case due to duplicates (untested)
                vecData = deref(it).second.data()
                vecSize = deref(it).second.size()
                # Search the element and remove it
                for j in range(vecSize):
                    if vecData[j] == idx:
                        vecData[j] = vecData[vecSize-1]
                        deref(it).second.pop_back()
                        break

            # Update `b`
            b[idx] = values[i]
```

- setup.py:

```py
# setup.py

from setuptools import setup
from Cython.Build import cythonize

setup(ext_modules=cythonize("maxtree.pyx"))
```

- main.py:

```py
# Usage:

import numpy as np
import maxtree
np.random.seed(0)
b = np.random.rand(750_000)
nchange = 1_000
ichange = np.random.randint(0, b.size, nchange).astype(np.int32)

tree = maxtree.MaxTree(b)
tree.getKlargest(nchange)
tree.update(b, ichange, b[ichange]*0.999)
```

- command to run: `python3 setup.py build_ext --inplace -q`

Comment: A huge thanks for the time and effort you put into writing your solution! Your in-depth knowledge on C++/C/python and performance optimizations is seriously astonishing. I'll soon test your solution. Likely `K < ~20 << nchange`, but this may not affect the runtime much, as you wrote the tree update is the bottleneck. A pity that Cython not supporting the newer C++ structures prevents further speed-ups. But a `3-4` performance increase is definitely very significant by itself, as the `argpartition` is the bottleneck of my code.

Comment: Given that `b` contains floating-point numbers acting much like as if they were randomly drawn from a distribution (even if they are not), the probability of having two identical values (among the `K` largest values!) should be quite (infinitesimally, if we ignore machine precision) small. That being said, we cannot exclude it happens, but it should be **very** unlikely.